# Javascript Minification Issues

Tags: javascript, minify

I've the following code:

```
getTrainPlanDetail: function(id){
        var df = new $.Deferred();
        $.post( config.api, addJSONHeaders("detail_fiche_entrainement",{"idRequete": id}), function(data){
            if (ajaxEval(data)){
              df.resolve(data);
            } else {
                df.fail(data);
            }
        }, 'json').fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            df.fail();
        });
        return df.promise();
    },
```

after minification it gets converted into:

```
getTrainPlanDetail: function(a) {
        var b = new $.Deferred;
        return $.post(config.api, addJSONHeaders("detail_fiche_entrainement", {idRequete: a}), function(a) {
            ajaxEval(a) ? b.resolve(a) : b.fail(a)
        }, "json").fail(function() {
            b.fail()
        }), b.promise()
    }
```

Do you notice the problem with the return?
I want to return the b.promise(); not the $.post
Can someone tell me why is this happening? To me it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *are* returning `b.promise()`. The minifier is making use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which returns its last operand:

```
return 1, 2; // returns 2
return 1, 2, 3; // returns 3
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. Thank you. (I'll mark as correct answer when allowed by stackoverflow)